# Haxe/OpenFL - Check if sprite is clicked

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am trying to create a sprite and if the sprite is clicked it prints out a message. I created a sprite but when I added a listener it gives me the errors:

```
src/Main.hx:26: characters 39-44 : Void -> Void should be Dynamic -> Void
src/Main.hx:26: characters 39-44 : For function argument 'listener'
```

I removed the listener and then it worked just fine what is the problem?

My main class:

```
package;


import openfl.display.Sprite;
import openfl.events.MouseEvent;
import openfl.display.SimpleButton;


class Main extends Sprite {

private var button:SimpleButton;
private var s:Spritetest;

public function new () {
    super ();

    this.mouseChildren = false;
    this.buttonMode = true;

    init();
}

public function init() {
    fillBackGround(0xff00ff, 640, 960);
    s = new Spritetest();
    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);
    addChild(s);

}

public function fillBackGround(color:Int, w:Int, h:Int) {
    this.graphics.beginFill(color);
    this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, w, h);
    this.graphics.endFill();
}

public function click() {
    trace("test");
}
```

}

my Sprite class:

```
package;

import openfl.display.Sprite;

class Spritetest extends Sprite {

public function new() {
    super();
    this.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
    this.graphics.drawRect(20 , 20, 40, 40);
    this.graphics.endFill();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The listener function signature must be `Dynamic -> Void`, because an `Event` (or `MouseEvent`) object will be passed as argument when you click.

Thus it should be like that:

```
public function click(e:Dynamic) {
   trace('test');
}
```

The OpenFL API mimics Flash's, and thus the `addEventListener` function works pretty much like documented here : 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()